# Specific action for each buttons in UIScrollView

Tags: objective-c, ipad, uiscrollview, uibutton

I have an `UIScrollView` page . On this `UIscrollView` I have different images inside buttons you can see it in below code, and I want to load this images in `UIWebView` when I press the buttons, My question is how can I know which button are click. Would you please give me some hint for implementing this?

I'm new to objective-C

Here is my action: I want to have one action for each images, rightnow I have just one action for all images, I one to have one for each image

```
 - (IBAction)openAction:(id)sender {

  NSLog(@"test");
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Give each button a unique tag, in your code or in Interface Builder.

Then in your action you can do:

```
- (IBAction)openAction:(id)sender {
   UIButton *b = (UIButton *)sender;
   NSLog(@"button %d is pressed", b.tag);
}
```

I see that you already give your imageviews tags. Those are not buttons! You should instead create UIButtons whose content are images. See UIButton's setImage:forState:

Edit: In response to your question below, here's an example:

```
NSMutableArray *bArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:kNumImages];
NSUInteger i;
for (i = 1; i <= kNumImages; i++)
{
    NSString *imageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"image%d.jpg", i];
    UIButton *btn = [[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom] retain];
    btn setImage:imageName forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    btn.tag = 100+i;
    [bArray addObject:btn];
}
```

Comment: Thanks, how can I know which button has which picture, would you please help me more

Comment: In your loop with i, where you're choosing the image, simply set the tag of the button to i (or to be safer, something like (100+i) so you don't have multiple tags equal to 0.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use Same Tag for Button. Use Different Tag for different button.
For ex [btn setTag:1] .
you can use [btn setTag:i]; 
Dynamic value

Answer (score 1):

The actual button is passed to the IBAction. Setting a tag on the button is one way of doing it. If you created outlets for all your buttons in Interface Builder, you can simply do something like this:

```
- (IBAction)openAction:(id)sender {
    UIButton *b = (UIButton *)sender;

    if ([b isEqual:self.outletButton1]) {
        // Do something with button 1
    }
    else if ([b isEqual:self.outletButton2]) {
        // Do something with button 2
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to add UIButton over UIImageView. Instead, you can set the image for UIButton like this.

```
    [btn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image1"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

You can access the image in the action like this:

```
- (IBAction)openAction:(id)sender {
  if([[btn currentImage] isEqual:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image1"]]){

  }
  NSLog(@"test");
 }
```